# Save form input to cookie JSON but exclude password

Tags: javascript, php, json, cookies, passwords

Posting my very first question on Stackoverflow after a long research.

I have a form and would like to store the input in a cookie JSON string.
It works so far so good with the follwing script. But due to security reasons i would like to exclude the password.

Any expert here who knows how to achieve that?

```
<script src="js.cookie.js"></script> //source: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

<script>
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeJSON = function () {
        var json = {};
        jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function (n, _) {
            json[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });
        return json;
    };
})(jQuery);

ensureNumber = function (n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);
    if (isNaN(n) || n <= 0) {
        n = 0;
    }
    return n;
};


saveFormToCookie = function (form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('id');
    var data = $(form).serializeJSON();
    Cookies.set(name, data, {expires: 1});

};

loadFormFromCookie = function (form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('id');
    var data = Cookies.get(name);

    if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    JSON.parse(data, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof (value) !== 'object') {
            var el = $(form).find('*[name="' + key + '"]');

            if (el.is('input')) {
                if (false) {
                    // code formatting stub
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'number') {
                    el.val(ensureNumber(value));
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
                    if (el.val() === value) $(el).prop('checked', true);
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'radio') {
                    $.each(el, function (_, elc) {
                        if (elc.value === value) $(elc).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                } else {
                    el.val(value);
                }
            } else if (el.is('select')) {
                el.val(value);
            } else if (el.is('textarea')) {
                el.val(value);
            }
        }
    });
};
</script> //source: https://gist.github.com/themactep/2714798
```

EDIT:

In addition to this i appreciate explaining why one should rather use PHP session to store users input data.

Comment: $_SESSION[] would be server-side (stored in server memory rather than client memory), so you don't have data stored on the client computer. The downside to that though is once a user exits the site the $_SESSION[] data is lost. Although there are ways around that via databases and alike.

Answer (score 0):

> The simplest way would be to cache the password value, clear the password field, saveFormToCookie, then repopulate the password if needed.

**Javascript**  ([jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/dp28tbun/))

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeJSON = function () {
        var json = {};
        jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function (n, _) {
            json[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });
        return json;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event){
          // Prevents the button from submitting the form
          event.preventDefault();

          var txtPassword = $("#txtPassword");
          var frmLogin = $("#frmLogin");

          //cache Password
          var cachedPassword = txtPassword.val();

          //Clear Password
          txtPassword.val("");

          // Save to cookie
          saveFormToCookie(frmLogin);

          // repopulate
          txtPassword.val(cachedPassword);    

          // To submit form as normal
          // use frmLogin.sumbit(); 
          // instead of $("#btnClear").click(); 
          $("#btnClear").click(); 
      });

      $("#btnClear").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

          $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], input[type=password]").val("");
      });

      $("#btnLoad").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();

           loadFormFromCookie($("#frmLogin"));
      });
});

ensureNumber = function (n) {
    n = parseInt(n, 10);
    if (isNaN(n) || n <= 0) {
        n = 0;
    }
    return n;
};


saveFormToCookie = function (form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('id');
    var data = $(form).serializeJSON();
    Cookies.set(name, data, {expires: 1});
};

loadFormFromCookie = function (form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('id');
    var data = Cookies.get(name);

    if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    JSON.parse(data, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof (value) !== 'object') {
            var el = $(form).find('*[name="' + key + '"]');

            if (el.is('input')) {
                if (false) {
                // code formatting stub
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'number') {
                    el.val(ensureNumber(value));
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
                    if (el.val() === value) $(el).prop('checked', true);
                } else if (el.attr('type') === 'radio') {
                    $.each(el, function (_, elc) {
                        if (elc.value === value) $(elc).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                } else {
                    el.val(value);
                }
            } else if (el.is('select')) {
                el.val(value);
            } else if (el.is('textarea')) {
                el.val(value);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="frmLogin" action="">
  <label for="txtUser">Username: </label><input id="txtUser" type="text" name="user"><br>
  <label for="txtPassword">Password: </label><input id="txtPassword" type="password" name="password"><br>
<br>
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear">
  <input id="btnLoad" type="button" value="Load from cookie">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
  display: block;
}
```

---

**Update** ([jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/dp28tbun/2/))

If you just want it to happen in the background just replace the saveFormToCookie function you had with:

```
saveFormToCookie = function (form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('id');
    var formCopy = $(form).clone();

    // remove password fields from copy
    formCopy.children("input[type='password']").remove();

    // serialize copy
    var data = formCopy.serializeJSON();
    Cookies.set(name, data, {expires: 1});
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick-Cordova. This looks like one path we could take. I was thinking to maybe just exclude any input of type password when the json is created. Something like 

`
jQuery.map($(this).serializeArray(), function (n, _) {

IF NOT INPUT TYPE PASSWORD:

            json[n['name']] = n['value'];

        });
`
In your approach there is still the string: password in the json. :-/

Comment: I updated my reply with an updated saveFormToCookie function. I think just replacing that with your current one would do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work:

My console shows that password is saved regardless the .remove (); 

`{%22password%22:%221234%22%2C%22username%22:%...`

Comment: Did you clear your cookies before you tested? I don't see password in my cookies created with https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/dp28tbun/2/. If you did clear your cookies. What browser are you using? It gets kind of nasty if you try to exclude in the serializeJSON function because you lose input type at that stage.

Comment: I did clear and deleted cookie manually too but the password string gets saved in the cookie anyway. Tested on Safari, Chrome, FF. Strange that in your fiddle i see that the password is indeed not in the JSON. Hmm :-(